# Example Discord slash command with choices

Tags: discord.js

I need to create a Discord slash command with fixed choices for input options.

My command is `/tip {token_name}`

What would the JSON request look like?

Comment: You seem to be asking us to write code for you. Please take some time to read [ask]. We do not write code for you. You must show your attempt, and should try to do some research.

Comment: What do you have problems with?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please see the Slash Commands section of the [Discord Documentation](https://discord.com/developers/docs/interactions/application-commands#slash-commands).

The example provided in the documentation is below. The `choices` array is used to set choices.

```json
{
    "name": "blep",
    "type": 1,
    "description": "Send a random adorable animal photo",
    "options": [
        {
            "name": "animal",
            "description": "The type of animal",
            "type": 3,
            "required": true,
            "choices": [
                {
                    "name": "Dog",
                    "value": "animal_dog"
                },
                {
                    "name": "Cat",
                    "value": "animal_cat"
                },
                {
                    "name": "Penguin",
                    "value": "animal_penguin"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "name": "only_smol",
            "description": "Whether to show only baby animals",
            "type": 5,
            "required": false
        }
    ]
}
```